# Problem with installing CUDA Toolkit on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda

I successfully installed CUDA Toolkit by following the process mentioned on the official site. But during installation, it also upgrades the Nvidia drivers. Currently `nvidia-driver-390` is working but after CUDA Toolkit installation it upgrades and those new drivers don't work. In Ubuntu 21.04, it was fine but now it's not working anymore. I have Quadro K1100M GPU in laptop.

Comment: Looks like 418 is the latest one for your hardware. Get your Nvidia working, then pick a cuda install method that does not install its own (wrong) version. See answers 1077061 and 1219761 on this site.

Comment: Yeah, I upgraded to 418 but its new number is 470 and after installing CUDA, drivers stop working. I tried many versions but no one is working. Even if I just install any driver from cuda repo it doesn't work.

Comment: I have encountered a similar issue. If one installs `nvidia-driver-495` and then attempts to install `nvidia-cuda-toolkit`, it will try to remove the `nvidia-driver-495` in the process - and it's my general understanding that you need both in order to run CUDA applications....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by the following process.

```
sudo apt purge cuda*
sudo apt purge nvidia*
sudo apt purge libnvidia*
sudo apt autoremove
```

**Removing all the stuff regarding nvidia is mandatory, otherwise you might face some installation issues.**

I found that my supported nvidia driver is `nvidia-driver-418` from [nvidia driver downloads](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx), later I found that ubuntu `nvidia-driver-418` has been moved to `nvidia-driver-470 (470.82.01)`, I don't know the theory behind this.

Then from [NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit Release Notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#title-new-cuda-tools) I got that `CUDA 11.4 Update 3` ships with `nvidia-driver-470 (470.82.01)` and it's done. Then simply I followed the process from [official documentation](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-11-4-3-download-archive?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu&target_version=20.04&target_type=deb_local) for local deb (Ubuntu 21.10 isn't available there but 20.04 works), and it worked.

In my case it was like:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2004.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2004.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.4.3/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-4-local_11.4.3-470.82.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-4-local_11.4.3-470.82.01-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu2004-11-4-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

Comment: Downloading from the nvidia website is ok, but then you loose automatic updates via apt. Isn't there a better way of fixing this?

Comment: I think it's better to go with Nvidia because in my case, Ubuntu didn't update the driver, it kept me on  `nvidia-driver-390` and my GPU supports 418(470) which I installed manually.